# What are Pros and Cons of using Library project(In Eclipse)in my existing Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, library-project

I am working on a Android app in which I would like to add plug and play module functionality ,Say I have Two android project

> [A] An app for capturing a image using camera and storing it in memory
>
> [B]Enabling map and locate current location .

now I want to add add this functionality in my Another Android app.While going [through android developer link](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html) and [Android Library Projects - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html) I figure out that to use plug and play module I have to make my above project as library project so that I can use it in my new app ,now my questions are

> [1](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html)  Is this only way to use library project to add plug and play module
>   functionally in my app or there are another way also?
>
> [2](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html)  what are the pros and cons of using library project in order to add
>   plug and play module functionally?

basically I am researching on how to add plug and play service in my android app and trying to find best solution ,so any clarity on this topic will be extremaly helpful !!!

thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to use a linked source folder. In Eclipse, you can set this up in the project settings in the Java Build Path section. You can choose some source code directory outside your project that will virtually be in your project's space (and other projects that use it will do the same). I find this to be handy just from an IDE UI standpoint when I'm co-developing a module along with an app or two. What I don't like about library projects is that they sometimes don't update correctly within your project so you have to rebuild it and your project or clean your project to continue. Also, the module is simpler because it's just a directory of source code files, not an entire Eclipse project.

One other downside of libraries is that they can introduce conflicts that can be a headache to fight. For example, your library might have a different version of the Android compatibility library in it than your main project, and therefore give you compile time errors. Or there are sometimes errors with duplicate libraries, and you have to go fool with the Order and Export settings of your project.

If your module is going to rely on String, layout, and image resources, etc. that are common to all apps that implement the module, then a library project will be easier to work with so you don't have to pass all your resources in through your module's class constructors and duplicate them in each project.

A third option is Gradle, although as far as I know, that would essentially just help automate one of the above two options. I'm not very familiar with Gradle.